# Cannot copy Red Evil Text in LyX on Windows

Tags: lyx, windows

I just installed the latest version of LyX for Windows (2.1.2). When I copy a RET and paste it, all I get is the first line of the RET. For example, I click Ctrl-L, enter some lines ("abc", "def", "ghi"), then select the entire RET and some text before and after it (to make sure my selection indeed includes everything), copy and paste. What I get from the paste is just the "abc". Is this a bug in LyX, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I do not see this on Ubuntu. Sounds like a bug in LyX on Windows. There are a few issues we've seen which have to do with creating temporary buffers and temp files on Windows. Perhaps this is the root cause. Can you please open a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac ?

Comment: @scottkosty I tried several times to register to the LyX trac site in order to open a bug report, but unfortunately I never received the validation email..

Comment: Can you please send an email to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org ? Also, can you try to register using a different email? (or with Gmail you can put a dot in your user name). Perhaps the confirmation email takes some time to arrive.

Comment: Done http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in LyX on Windows.